# How do I verify the version of RSK running on a node?

Tags: rpc, rsk

I have RPC access to a private deployment of an RSK node,
but no direct access to the file system.
How can I check what version of the RSK node is running on that system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without direct access to the file system,
you cannot *verify* the version of RSKj (the RSK node implementation)
that is running on that machine.
However, you can check the version that it *claims* to be running,
using an RPC request: `web3_clientVersion`.

For example, using the public public node:

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":1}' \
  https://public-node.rsk.co/
```

(replace `https://public-node.rsk.co/` with the
RPC endpoint URL of your target deployment.)

This should output the following:

```json
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"RskJ/3.0.0/Linux/Java1.8/IRIS-ba01ea2"}
```

You can then view RSKj's tagged releases on the RSKj github repo.
For example, the above output corresponds to
https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj/releases/tag/IRIS-3.0.0

---

Note that if you see the following output:

```json
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"RskJ/2.2.0/Linux/Java1.8/PAPYRUS-dev"}
```

That means you are still running an older version of the RSK node,
and prior to the Iris consensus changes,
and you should upgrade to the latest version and re-sync your blocks!